# Redirect in a view screws up the original controller action (Yii)?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, yii

I have an action in a controller which renders a view (let's say view 1) with a form supposed to be submitted and there's a link in the form so that user can do sth else before completing the form. The link is actually another action (using `CHtml::link(route)` in the same controller) which opens up another view (view 2, which being rendered in a new tab).

Weird thing is, once the link is clicked, the original submit action does not work anymore. When submitted button clicked, the view 1 will redirect to view 2 for a strange reason(-_-!). What might be the cause?

So, another way to ask the same question is that, how to write a link in the form so that user can do sth else before submitting current form and when they've done, it return to the original form and coutinue what they want to?

I'm a php newbie and I'm using Yii FX.

Comment: I think you are using [`redirect()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail) where you actually should to use [`CHtml.link()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail). One issues a HTTP redirect while the other creates a clickable link.

Comment: @DaSourcerer sorry actually what I wrote IS a "CHtml::link()" but with another route (controller/action2) inside it.

Comment: Does the link contain any javascript? The only way this would happen is if the form's action were being replaced. To prevent any sort of user error, can you confirm that if you don't click on the link, the form submits as expected?

Comment: @Kyle I've checked the source, the form's action property IS BEING CHANGED when I clicked the link. If I refresh the page again, the form would submit as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the reason of this bug is because the link I write is like this

```
CHtml::link('click me!','#',array('submit'=>array('action2',GET_PARAMETERS),'target'=>'_blank');
```

This link hides the url but somehow screws up the form and change the form action to 'action2'.

However after I changed it to

```
CHtml::link('click me!',$this->createUrl('action2',GET_PARAMETERS),array('target'=>'_blank'));
```

Then it works with no problem.